# R knitr ordered list from dataframe

Tags: r, knitr, r-markdown

I'm trying to embed an R data.frame column as an ordered list in my `knitr` pdf output. So far my best atempt is:

````
```{r df, echo=FALSE, results='asis'}
  df <- read.csv2(file.path(filePath,'data.csv'))
  for (i in nrow(df)){
    print(paste(i, '. ', df[i,3]))
  }
```
````

which results in this output:

```
[1] “8 . At vero eos et accusam et justo duo dolores et ea rebum.”
```

I would like this to be a eight-point ordered list that fits in with normal text output. Does anybody know how to achieve this?

Comment: Can you show what the input looks like and what the output should look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you want to print a markdown list, you can use the related helper function from the `pander` package, which provides many convenient ways for R->markdown conversion. Quick demo:

```
> pandoc.list(head(rownames(mtcars)), style = 'ordered')

1. Mazda RX4 
2. Mazda RX4 Wag 
3. Datsun 710 
4. Hornet 4 Drive 
5. Hornet Sportabout 
6. Valiant 

<!-- end of list -->
```

Comment: Thanks, that did exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

Use `cat()` instead of `print()`, e.g.

```
cat(paste(i, '. ', df[i,3]), '\n')
```

Actually you do not need to increment `i`, since [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/README.html) does not care the actual numbers in the list (this may be a little surprising). You may just use `1` for all items, e.g.

```
1. foo
1. bar
```

so you may replace the for-loop with

```
cat(paste('1.', df[, 3]), sep = '\n')
```